# Android Up button with appcompat on Gingerbread, title not clickable

Tags: android, android-appcompat

We are using the appcompat library to use the ActionBar down to Gingerbread and we are enabling the home button on activities (also including both versions of parentActivityName setting in the manifest).

But one thing that testers have reported as different is the "size" of the up button. On newer devices you can click on the up arrow, the logo, or the title of the activity. But on Gingerbread only the smaller area of the arrow and the logo is clickable. The title is not clickable.

Is there a way to get this behavior to be the same and have the title clickable as well on Gingerbread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no native way of doing it.

Making both the title and the logo clickable was a feature introduced in the later versions.

But yeah, you can always make a custom view and set it as the view of the ActionBar.

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

Comment: don't like it, but definitely seems to be some solution :(((((( thx